# monitoringDidFailForRegion calls only on ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have developed ios application which is supports for both iphone & iPad.

In that application I have integrated location tracking feature.

Here is how I implemented it.

```
     //start monitoring for region for checked in location
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longtitude);
    regionalMonitor = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:centerCoordinate        radius:REGIONAL_MONITOR_RADIOUS identifier:@"checkedIn"];
    [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:regionalMonitor];


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
        NSLog(@"didEnterRegion");
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
        NSLog(@"didExitRegion");
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Region monitoring failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

}
```

This methods are perfectly working in iphone application. But when I try to executes them in ipad

```
monitoringDidFailForRegion
```

method will be called. But it works perfectly in ipad simulator.

Is there any particular reason for it, or is this device oriented bug. because if I comment

```
[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:regionalMonitor];
```

Then it will not called  monitoringDidFailForRegion method

log message   - Region monitoring failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that geofencing is not supported on WiFi iPads, or at least older ones.

Try printing the value of `[locationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:CLRegion]`. If that is true (`1`), than it should work. Otherwise, it's unsupported on the current device.

Comment: Hello thanks for ur tip. i have checked it with this method regionMonitoringAvailable . it returns false. but i realy need this thing to work. is thr any solution for this

Comment: @Mr.G: Not really. Disable your feature on iPads that arn't 3g/4g is all I can say.

Comment: yeah i agree . i ve found a nice article saying that ipad 2 wi-fi version doent has regional monitor feature.

Comment: do you share with me this article? i'm having the same problem... :/